# Importing users with JSON into Gigya

Tags: gigya

I made a JSON file as documented here: http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Users

But I can't find where to import the file.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in Gigya's [documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/RaaS), "A migration to the Gigya platform is performed by exporting data from your current system to a JSON file and sending it to Gigya to import."

To schedule such a data migration, you will need to coordinate with the Account Manager assigned to your company's account at Gigya. They will be able to provide with further instructions.